# JKS keystore file in the classpath not found

Tags: java, ssl, classpath, keystore

I am trying to configure SSL with JKS certs, which are stored in keystore.jks file.
I have this piece of code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SSLConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Value("${server.ssl.key-store}")
    private String keyStore;

    @Value("${server.ssl.key-store-password}")
    private String keyStorePassword;

    @PostConstruct
    private void configureSSL() {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", keyStore);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePassword);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", keyStorePassword);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreProvider", "SUN");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
    }
}
```

When I specify in the application.properties file value
***server.ssl.key-store=classpath:config/keystore.jks***
I am getting an IOException, saying that file is not found.
If I specify
***server.ssl.key-store=src/main/resources/config/keystore.jks***
everything is working fine.
When I will deploy my service, there won't be src directory.
How can I make it working from the classpath?

Comment: How are you packaging your application to be deployed?

Comment: It is packaged as JAR file

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to introduce method to resolve absolute path:

```
 public String absolutePath(String resource) {
        return  Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"))
                .resolve(resource).toAbsolutePath().toString(); 
    } 

@PostConstruct
private void configureSSL() {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", absolutePath(keyStore));
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", absolutePath(keyStore));
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", absolutePath(keyStorePassword));
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", absolutePath(keyStorePassword));
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreProvider", "SUN");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "JKS");
}
```

Comment: Nope, it is not working. It is throwing NPE inside this function.  Resolve method return NULL.